# How to insert a textfield value in td

Tags: jquery, html

i need to insert value from textfield in a table  , with jQuery .
I have a table with three cells , and i use a jQuery function to append element on my table , but i can't get the value of my textfield in the td .

**this is my table:**

```
<table id="tableCmp" border name="tableCmp" style="width:25%;border-collapse:collapse;">

<tr>
<th width="5%"></th>
<th>Intitule Compagnie</th>     
<th width="15%">Action</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

**this is my text field:**

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

**this is my function:**

```
function showdata()
 {
 $('#tableCmp').append('<tr><td  style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" id="myTextEditBox"></td><td>$('#text').val()</td><td><input type="button" value="M" /><input type="button" value="X" /></td></tr>');
 }
```

Comment: Misquoting in your code. Is that just typo in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function showdata()
 {
   $('#tableCmp').append('<tr><td  style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" id="myTextEditBox"></td><td>' + $("#text").val() +'</td><td><input type="button" value="M" /><input type="button" value="X" /></td></tr>');
 }
```

Comment: I guess `$("#text").val()` should be unwrapped from quoting :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Corrected it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have added $("#text").val() inside of the brackets, Try using this

```
$('#tableCmp').append('<tr><td  style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" id="myTextEditBox"></td><td>' + $('#text').val() + '</td><td><input type="button" value="M" /><input type="button" value="X" /></td></tr>');
```